# print function returning syntax error when used in Python3.6 IDLE (on MacOS)

Tags: python-3.6

I have a text file that contains some basic passwords and some variants of those basic passwords. They are typed out together like this:

```
qwerty, qwerty1
password, password1
default, default 1
123, 12345, 123456
```

I am trying to take these values and split them, storing them in a tuple and then print out the values as 'Password' and then any variants, but I am getting a syntax error on the print BIF? (I am aware this will not print out the password '123456', I am just trying to solve the syntax error first.)

```
for each_line in passwords: 
    (passwd, passwd_variant) = each_line.split(',',1) 
     print(f'Password: {passwd}, Variant {passwd_variant}')
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

normally if I was writing a script, in the editor I would put print on a new line, however a new line in IDLE simply executes the code above it. is there a shortcut or something to do a carriage return and write the print statement on a new line and if so, is that the cause of the syntax error and why?

Cheers

EDIT: I would like my output to be this

[image: passwords.txt split output]

Answer (score -2):

Finally discovered that you need to hit Enter after the for in statement, this will then take you to a new line inside for in statement. Was up all night trying to work it out, maybe my fresh brain helped this morning.